# onPostExecute does not get triggered

Tags: java, android, web-services

So I have created a webservice call class that calls my webservice which extends on AsyncTask:

```
public class WebServiceLoginCall extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
             if(loginStatus){
                 System.out.println("onpost has been executed");
                 //Navigate to Home Screen
                 loginIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                 startActivity(loginIntent);
                //prevents user to go back to the login screen
                finish();
                }else{
                    //Set Error message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed. Check your details.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured. Check your mobile connection.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        System.out.println("doinbackground triggered");
        try {
            loginStatus = Webservice.invokeLoginWS(loginUser.get_userEmail(), loginUser.get_userPassword());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("an error occured with the webservice");
        }

        return loginStatus;
    }

}
```

When the user presses the login button, I use the following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnLogin:
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        loginUser = new User();
        loginUser.set_userEmail(email.getText().toString());
        loginUser.set_userPassword(password.getText().toString());

        //starts loging webservice
        WebServiceLoginCall task = new WebServiceLoginCall();
        //executes the login task
        task.execute();

    break;
```

When I check, the doInBackground is triggered in my console, but the onPostExecute is not.  Is there anything that I am doing wrong?  The doInBackground does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: use @Override with onPostExecute()

Comment: AsyncTask should be defined as: AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>, and onPostExecute(Result result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make following two changes

1.Use `public class WebServiceLoginCall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean >`
  instead of `public class WebServiceLoginCall extends AsyncTask`

2.Use

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
// your code
}
```

instead of just

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
// your code
}
```

[Refer Android- Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Explanation:

In your case if you put @Override on onPostExecute() without extending the generic Asynctask, you will get a compile time error. Hence you will have to make above two changes.

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

because you are calling a different method your post execute wont execute ever execute if you defined it like your code

use

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(boolean result) {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your not Override the onPostExecute() method
add : `@Override`

like this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
             if(loginStatus){
                 System.out.println("onpost has been executed");
                 //Navigate to Home Screen
                 loginIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                 startActivity(loginIntent);
                //prevents user to go back to the login screen
                finish();
                }else{
                    //Set Error message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed. Check your details.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error occured. Check your mobile connection.",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add the @Override to your postexecute

2) If your asynctask takes parameter then execute your asynctask like this:

```
 task.execute(Object);
```

because your AsyncTask takes Object

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0)
```

3) Your doInBackground returns a Boolean loginStatus value but your onPostExecute(Void result) takes in void.

Hope it helps